# Get ID of updated record in Oracle update trigger pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I have an employee table and trying to log the update/delete operations of employee table into a log table. 
Emp table:

```
ID NAME ReviewerID
1   A   101
2   B   102
3   C   101
```

If I perform an update operation, then I want to retrieve the ID of that particular record

```
DECLARE 
P_ID INTEGER:
....
WHEN UPDATING('ReviewerID') THEN
SELECT ID INTO P_ID 
FROM EMP 
WHERE ReviewerID = :new.ReviewerID
.....
```

If I update ReviewerID of B to 101, then I get an error of multiple rows fetched which I believe is true. How to retrieve ID ? Please help me with the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the value in the :NEW pseudo-row, which contains the values which are present after the UPDATE occurs. It looks like you want to do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_UPDATE_TRIGGER
  AFTER UPDATE OF EMPLOYEE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.ReviewerID <> :NEW.ReviewerID THEN
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_LOG
      (ID, ReviewerID)
    VALUES
      (:NEW.ID, :NEW.ReviewerID);
  END IF;
END EMPLOYEE_UPDATE_TRIGGER;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Yeah! Figured it. Beginner mistakes. Thank you